# Move cursor to other textbox during IME-composition

Tags: javascript, html, user-input, cjk, ime

I want to move the cursor to another textinput field with javascript, while the user types. When radicals are composed (korean, japanese, chinese) it causes unexpected behaviour.

E.g. if the user types `나` in the first textbox, the cursor should be moved to the second. However, when continuing to type in the second textbox, the `나` from the first textbox is still persistent.

```
[|   ]  [    ]      cursor in first box
[나   ]  [|   ]      typed 나 and cursor move
[나   ]  [난|  ]      typed ㄴ
```

Only typing `ㄴ+ㅏ+ㄴ` produces the characters `나, 난` instead of `나, ㄴ`.

```js
const a = document.getElementById("a");
const b =  document.getElementById("b");
a.oninput = e => { if (a.value == '나') b.focus(); };
```

```html
<input type="text" id="a">
<input type="text" id="b">
```

**I want to support Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera, Edge on Windows and MacOS.**

---

A more extensive log.

```js
const a = document.getElementById("a");
const b =  document.getElementById("b");
const c =  document.getElementById("c");

[a, b].forEach(el => {
  let log = e => c.textContent += `${el.id} ${event.type}: ${event.data}\n`;

  el.addEventListener("blur", log);
  el.addEventListener("keydown", log);
  el.addEventListener("compositionstart", log);
  el.addEventListener("compositionupdate", log);
  el.addEventListener("compositionend", log);
  el.addEventListener("input", log);
});

a.addEventListener("input", e => {
  if (a.value == '나') b.focus();
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="a">
<input type="text" id="b">
<br><pre type="text" id="c"></pre>
```

Output:

```
a keydown: undefined
a compositionstart: 
a compositionupdate: ㄴ
a input: ㄴ
a keydown: undefined
a compositionupdate: 나
a input: 나
a compositionend: 나
a blur: undefined
b keydown: undefined
b compositionstart: 
b compositionupdate: 난
b input: 난
// on clicking somewhere else => blurring the b field
b compositionend: 난
b blur: undefined
```

Comment: To test it, go to the first textbox, then type `난`. I'm also open to hacks.

Comment: Note that the platform is also important, macOS IME works as you want, which also means I can't really test from here since I don't have a win machine, and that I'll need your feedback. You might want  to try listening to the *compositionupdate* event along with the `input` one. For instance how does [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4pqg7vdo/) acts for you? An other possiblity is that the character you have at that time is actually two characters `"나"` in that case [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4pqg7vdo/) should work.

Comment: Thank you for your input. This is valuable information. I would want to support major browser on MacOS, Windows and Android. Should I ask individual questions or do you think a one-fits-all solution exists?

Comment: A single question is fine here. But could you tell me how it went using the fiddles I linked to?

Comment: Yes, sorry, same behaviour as before. Firefox works, but Chrome doesnt.

Comment: Ah, very weird. Can you add logs there to see if the event works fine, and what's the `.value` is when they fire?

Comment: Hi Kaiido, I tried to comply with your request and added something at the end of the answer. Was that what you meant?

Comment: Yes thanks. I first misunderstood the situation, the events are fine, the detection of the text to, what isn't is that the compositionend that should happen when the input is blurred doesn't happen... Not sure why, sounds very much like a bug worth a report. I'll try to reach a windows machine tomorrow.

Comment: ... just tried for 3 hours without any result... The closest I came was switching the `type` of the input to `"tel"` in order to deactivate the IME in windows Chrome, but first that didn't work at all in macOs Firefox (switching to my default latin IME instead), and in Chrome that would produce the 니은 character `ㄴ` literally without any way to compose it after...

Answer (score 1):

Well, it was pretty easy to do so. You just need to call `blur` on `a`.

```js
const a = document.getElementById("a");
const b =  document.getElementById("b");
a.oninput = e => { if (a.value == '나') { b.focus();a.blur(); } };
```

```html
<input type="text" id="a">
<input type="text" id="b">
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a good solution for Firefox, but not for Chrome or Opera. Do you know a cross-browser solution?

Comment: Well, I tested it with the character `L` (English character) because I don't have those characters on my keyboard. And it just works fine for me in Chrome v87 and Firefox too.

Comment: Well, roman characters do not use the IME composition, which is mentioned in the title. The problem only occurs *"when radicals are composed (korean, japanese, chinese)"*.

Comment: The blur algorithm is called on the currently focused element when the focus() method is called on an other element. i.e, this does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I Used Jquery to generate a cross browser solution . Tell me it works well pal !.

```html
<input type="text" id="a">
<input type="text" id="b">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
const a = document.getElementById("a");
const b =  $("#b");
a.oninput = e => { if (a.value == 'c') b.trigger('focus'); };
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. The behaviour is the same as in my original problem. Take a look at [this codepen gif](https://i.imgur.com/tcYsQqp.gif).